# split() PHP method changed with explode() but still gives me same error

Tags: php, posix-ere

I work on some php project for university. Need to create simple PHP chat client. I done that but in response file that do me split of string I have this message:[image]

I tried to change with explode() but it still gives me same error. Restarted apache and cleaned but still have same error. Can somebody tell me what is catch to solve this.

My response.php file is:

```
<?php
$lastreceived=$_POST['lastreceived'];
$room_file=file("room1.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
for($line=0;$line<count($room_file);$line++){
$messageArr=str_split("<!@!>",$room_file[$line]);
if($messageArr[0]>$lastreceived)echo $messageArr[1]."<br>";
}
echo "<SRVTM>".$messageArr[0];
?>
```

Comment: If it's still complaining about `split()`, you edited the wrong file. Changes in PHP code will usually show up immediately, no server restart should be necessary.

Comment: What you see is _not_ an error, it is a notice what you are using a function that might be missing in future releases of php. Such notice is only displayed if you tell php to do so. So for production sites you want to disable visualization of notices and the like. You can configure that behaviour inside your `php.ini` file.

Comment: ok... will try to edit php.ini

Comment: show us receive.php .. because there is the split call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_split` instead.

```
array preg_split ( string $pattern , string $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int $flags = 0 ]] )
```

In your case:

```
preg_split ("/<!@!>/",$room_file[$line]);
```

Comment: yes I tryed but it does not show me as function preg_split just as simple txt.